# python: permanent execution program date dependant

Tags: python, sys

I wrote a script.py collecting data from the web from monday to friday. The script is usually executed from another script in the main function. I want it to close on friday and open monday automatically, and run from monday to friday.

At the moment I am obliged to run it manually every monday.
I wrote some code to stop it automatically on fridays. Basically it looks like this

```
import sys
import time

if strftime("%a %H:%M", gmtime()) != "Fri 20:00":
    ...code...
else:
    sys.exit()
```

how to run the main script permanently and open the other script automatically when needed? hep me to improve this please thanks.

**EDIT** actually I will reformulate the question:

Is there a proper way to **run prermanently** a script, besides doing:

```
while 1!=0:
    ...code here
```

Comment: If there is one main loop in your program that should be execute again and again, then do it with `while True:`

Comment: **while true:** Is what i was searching, thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have any option to automatically schedule the program to start on mondays, with cron or windows task scheduler?

Alternatley, you could write a separate program that runs permanently and controlls the startup and/or shutdown of the script.py.

Comment: yes, i would like to write a programs that runs permanently and control the other... But how can you do this properly? I don't want code like: while 1!=0 : ...

Comment: You have a few options, but first consider that in effect the system (assuming unix or windows) already has a permanently running program you can use to control the running of other programs (IE: cron or task scheduler)

To write your own program, I would look at the python subprocess module as a starting point. - and if you want to avoid a 'while True:' block in you code, you may have to start looking at a threaded task scheduler that 'wakes up' at the appropriate time, rather than a polling - loop. The threaded scheduler is more complex to implement than the polling loop.

Answer (score 0):

For your reformulated question, theres nothing wrong with using

```
while True:
  do things in a loop forever
```

If that is indeed how the code needs to run.

It is avoidable if you want to, you could avoid it by restructuring your code so that it does not need to run in an infinite loop. There is no magic way to have a script 'keep running in a loop forever' without using a loop construct.

Though I'm wondering.  DO you not like

while 1!=0:

because it looks a bit silly to say 1!=0  ?

while True:

Is a perfectly neat alternative.